# Differences between pool.map and pool.imap_unordered when the worker throws an exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Say I do this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    print x
    raise OverflowError 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    pool.map(f, range(10))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

out:

```
0
3
6
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 9, in <module>
    pool.map(f, range(10))
  File "/Users/usualme/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/Users/usualme/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
OverflowError
```

Now I replace `map` by `imap_unordered`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    print x
    raise OverflowError 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

out:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test0.py", line 9, in <module>
6
7
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
8
  File "/Users/usualme/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, in next
9
    raise value
OverflowError
```

My questions:

- for `map`: why is it jumping from 0 to 3, 6, and 9?
- for `imap_unordered`: why does it go all the way to 9 this time? What's different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map`,`imap`, and `imap_unordered` process data in *chunks*. By their nature, they are prepared to submit those chunks to multiple processes in parallel.

> for imap_unordered: why does it go all the way to 9 this time? What's
>   different?

For `imap` (and presumably `imap_unordered`), [the default chunksize is 1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap). Thus, `f` will actually start to execute for all values.

You can check this behaviour by passing the `chunksize` argument. If you provide `chunksize=1` to `map`, you'll get behaviour similar to your other example.

> for map: why is it jumping from 0 to 3, 6, and 9?

Although it's not mentioned in the documentation, it seems `map`'s default `chunksize` is "smarter". Here, it looks like the chunk size was 3, so the chunks will be `[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9]]`.

I'm not sure why all this still happens when you only have one process, but my guess is that the implementation agglomerates all results *before* checking them. Exceptions, IIRC, are caught in the child process and serialized over IPC - they're a result as any other.

Comment: The `chunksize` algorithm `map` uses is: `chunksize, extra = divmod(len(<iterable passed to map>), <processes in pool> * 4)); if extra: chunksize +=1`. So in this case: `divmod(10, 1*4) == (2, 2)`, so that gives a `chunksize` of 3.